# Filtering JS array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have strange issue filtering array in typescript.
Here is my object:

#### Sigma.model.ts

```
export class Sigma {
sigmaId: number;
name: string;
userId: number;
starId: string;    
}
```

``

starId has comma separated ids.(ex: 3,4)

I need to filter an array- allStars with the star ids in Sigma object.
Let allStars contain objects with star ids 1,2,3,4,5. Finally sigStars should contain allStar objects with ids 3,4 only
The code is as follows.

#### filter.component.ts

```
selectedFilter(filter) {
 const starIds = filter.sigma.split(','); // example-> const starIds = [5,6];

for (const id in starIds) {
    this.sigStars = this.allStars.filter(star => star.sid === id);
}
}
```

However, when I debug this, in the for loop, the 'const id' always has value "0". It does not take the value of starIds i.e.[3,4]

Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: what is filter ? post the alue of json

Comment: filter is sigma array - filter:Sigma[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) like

```
starIds.forEach(id=>{
 this.sigStars = this.allStars.filter(star => star.sid === id);
})
```

Also your logic seems to be wrong as it will loop and filter foreach itration so instead of using foreach loop you can filter like

```
this.sigStars = this.allStars.filter(star => starIds.includes(star.sid));
```

Comment: I tried both. It does not filter the array. I get no results.

Comment: @Techie then add you sample json to your question.what does `allStars` consists is it array of `Sigma `?